How to express a candle in a burning state?
We say "I lit the candle" to express an action.
Can I say "the candle is lit" to express the candle in a burning state?
I think we say "something is burning" when we emphasize that thing is being destroyed.
However, a candle is designed to be burned. "The candle is burning" might signify the meaning the candle is being destroyed.
We say "I lit the candle" because the candle is designed to be burned.
If we say "I burned the candle", we emphasize I destroyed the candle.

“My candle burns at both ends;
It will not last the night;
But ah, my foes, and oh, my friends—
It gives a lovely light!”
― Edna St. Vincent Millay, A Few Figs from Thistles A very famous poem.

A Candle is Burning
(Tune: Away in the Manger)
A candle is burning, a flame warm and bright,
A candle of hope in December’s dark night https://mrsblackmore.weebly.com/uploads/1/9/7/1/19718463/a_candle_is_burning.pdf A candle burns. There was a candle buning on the table.

You only ever burn the midnight oil. I ever heard of anyone lighting it.

oops: burning

"something is burning" just means it is on fire, not necessarily being destored by the fire. "burning down", does mean that it is being destroyed.

But, But, But,... A candle is destroyed when you use it as intended. The destruction is slow, but it is utterly complete. I've got this one brass candlestick, and some high-quality candles that fit it, and if I leave a candle burning until the flame goes out, there will be nothing left but a little bit of blackened wick sitting in the bottom of the socket. There's not even a smear of wax left behind.

@SolomonSlow - Yes, of course; but you burn a candle to achieve its intended purpose, not just to destroy it as you burn rubbish or private papers.

Yes,  a lit candle or the candle is lit.  "Lit" is one of these participles that has become, or is becoming, an adjective.
But "burning" is also used:

Keep lit candles away from drafts and vibrations. Do not touch or move the candle whilst it is burning.

(source)

Once lit, keep the candle burning for at least two hours at a time. Burning for less time can make the candle tunnel.

(source)

Your source 1 also says: Do not burn your candle on or near anything that can catch fire. which is useful in terms of his question...

Lighted candle is more idiomatic than lit candle. (See this Ngram).
(In response to comments) Well, it feels much more idiomatic to me (70+). According to one of the results, Ebenezer Brewer in 1882 went so far as to say that 'lit candle' was incorrect, but in recent decades it seems to be creeping into acceptability.
Burn doesn't always mean 'destroy by burning', if the reference is to a candle or oil lamp. We can speak of 'a candle burning in the window', for example.

And, for that matter, electric lights shining out windows at night can be said to be "lights left burning" and such, even though there's no fire.

Your ngram shows "lighted candle" being gradually overtaken by "lit candle". "Lighted" is still around, but to me it sounds distinctly old-fashioned. It may also be regional.

I would certainly understand "lighted", but I'm personally more used to hearing "lit", and that's the word choice I usually would make myself.  On that basis, I claim that "lit" is more idiomatic in my part of the world.

I find "lighted candle" sufficiently odd that I would suspect it might be a non-native speaker saying it.

lighted and lit are used in different contexts.

What is your flavor of English, Kate? I tried the Ngram and found the pattern you describe in both BrE and AmE but I'm with the other commenters who found this odd. My ignorance is even deeper: I would have called lighted candle outright wrong, even, but I would clearly have been incorrect to do so. So I'm wondering if there's a dialectical aspect to this.

@terdon - British English, widely read.

Crud. I forgot I don't have the rep to edit directly here. I made a minor edit (changed your bold to italics) so I could retract my overhasty downvote, but it needs to be approved. Sorry Kate, and please ping me if you edit so I can change the -1 to a +1.

Out of curiosity, would you say a 'well-lighted room' or a 'well-lit room' (or something else)?  Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21198/whats-the-difference-between-well-lighted-and-well-lit

@paulgarrett, But of course, when we say that an electric light is "burning," that's really a metaphor that recalls the days when there was no other way to make light in dark places except by the use of open flames: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000SEWJ0M/

I strongly disagree, "lighted candle" sounds very unidiomatic to me (a 30 year old native Standard Southern British English speaker). I'm also very surprised at the n-grams results, but looking at the actual instances, the majority appear to be Christian texts, possibly aiming to slightly mirror more old-fashioned styles often found in Bible translations. Given that it seems that even in British English (which currently shows a slight preference for "lighted candle" in the n-gram plot) "lit candle" is strongly preferred in general use

@JimmyJames - I'm not sure, but I would describe a room with many lights as 'brightly-lit'.

@Tristan - But they  also include physics textbooks ('place a lighted candle in a sealed container') and other technical works.

sure, there "lighted candle" is used in other works, but the lead it has over "lit candle" disappears if we exclude Christian texts, indicating that, in general, it is not more idiomatic (in current use)

You could also describe the candle's state by saying that it is alight — which means that it's:

burning, lit, on fire.

and/or that it's:

shining with light; luminous, radiant



The candle is burning
The candle is lit

Both are fine and essentially mean the same thing, but 'burning' perhaps emphasises the candle being used up - a candle "burns down" and then goes out. Maybe "lit" is the better description of a candle's condition when it is emitting light.
